# Check If Tweet with ID Has Been Retweeted

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, sttwitter

I have an app that shows tweets on a map and when one is selected it shows more details for the tweet (twitter handle, the tweet, profile pic, etc.) There are buttons for favoriting and retweeting the tweet. The app uses STTwitter to interact with the Twitter API and authenticates the user of the app with `twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];` For retweeting and favoriting in the tweet detail view, I do this:

```
- (IBAction)retweet:(id)sender {
    [twitter postStatusRetweetWithID:tweetID successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {

        UIAlertView *retweetSuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Retweeted!" message:@"You have retweeted this post." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [retweetSuccess show];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *retweetFailure = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Retweet Failed!" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [retweetFailure show];

    }];
}

- (IBAction)favorite:(id)sender {
    [twitter postFavoriteCreateWithStatusID:tweetID includeEntities:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {

        UIAlertView *favoriteSuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Favorited!" message:@"You have favorited this post." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [favoriteSuccess show];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *favoriteFailure = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Favorite Failed!" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [favoriteFailure show];

    }];
}
```

How can I detect if a tweet has already been retweeted or favorited by the user so I can show a different button image for the retweet and favorite buttons?

Comment: You'll want to have a look at this portion of the API: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

I'm not sure if there's an STTwitter analogy for this REST API call, so I won't offer an official answer, but this URL should at least get you onto the right path.